# Bibtex not showing in Latex Doc when inserted in main.tex

Tags: latex, bibtex

I'm trying to include the following in my latex doc (references.tex)

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{inception,
author={C. {Szegedy} and {Wei Liu} and {Yangqing Jia} and P. {Sermanet} and S. {Reed} and D. {Anguelov} and D. {Erhan} and V. {Vanhoucke} and A. {Rabinovich}},
booktitle={2015 IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR)},
title={Going deeper with convolutions},
year={2015},
volume={},
number={},
pages={1-9},
keywords={convolution;decision making;feature extraction;Hebbian learning;image classification;neural net architecture;resource allocation;convolutional neural network architecture;resource utilization;architectural decision;Hebbian principle;object classification;object detection;Computer architecture;Convolutional codes;Sparse matrices;Neural networks;Visualization;Object detection;Computer vision},
doi={10.1109/CVPR.2015.7298594},
ISSN={1063-6919},
month=Jun,
address={Boston, MA}
}

@InProceedings{vgg,
  author       = "Karen Simonyan and Andrew Zisserman",
  title        = "Very Deep Convolutional Networks for Large-Scale Image Recognition",
  booktitle    = "International Conference on Learning Representations",
  year         = "2015",
  month        = May,
  address      = {San Diego, CA}
}

@inproceedings{dean2012large,
  title={Large scale distributed deep networks},
  author={Dean, Jeffrey and Corrado, Greg and Monga, Rajat and Chen, Kai and Devin, Matthieu and Mao, Mark and Senior, Andrew and Tucker, Paul and Yang, Ke and Le, Quoc V},
  booktitle={Advances in neural information processing systems},
  pages={1223--1231},
  month = dec,
  year={2012},
  address = {Lake Tahoe, NV}
}
```

However, when I include this in my latex doc, it doesn't show, any idea what is wrong here?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{acronym}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Large}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{Scaling A Neural Network Based Flower Counting Application}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

\input{cover}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter*{Permission To Use}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Permissions To Use}
\input{sections/permissions}
    
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\input{sections/abstract}

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\input{sections/acknowledgements}

\newgeometry{top=0mm, bottom=25mm}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}

\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

\newgeometry{top=25mm, bottom=25mm}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}
\include{sections/abbreviations} 

\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{sections/introduction}

\chapter{Section Two Title}
\input{sections/section/section-2}

\chapter{Section Three Title}
\input{sections/section/section-3}

\chapter{Section Four Title}
\input{sections/section/section-4}

\chapter{Section Five Title}
\input{sections/section/section-5}

\chapter{Conclusion}
\input{sections/conclusion}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix Title}
\input{sections/appendix}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that does not rely on files we don't have access to? If I remove all these files and insert a citation, your example works fine

Comment: This might be easier: https://www.overleaf.com/read/nznjrfcwhhth

Comment: You must not ignore error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Never ignore error messages. Have a look at the tiny red rectangle at the top right, this tells you where the problem is.

Multiple problems:

- You must not use math commands like `^` in normal text mode

  ```
  \acro{P$^2$IRC}{Plant Phenotyping and Imaging Research Center}
  ```
- The command `\ection` is not defines, I assume you mean `\section`? (there are several occasions)
- you must `\cite{...}` at least one entry from your `.bib` file

Comment: i cleaned up most of these silly errors, but whats the full format for /cite{..}?

Comment: @Kode_12 for example `\cite{dean2012large}`